# What does it mean for a function to be "smooth on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$"?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Guillemin&Pollack, the notions of smooth maps between manifolds and smooth maps from an arbitrary subset to a manifold are defined. However in the problem sets, the term "smooth on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$" is used. What does this mean? In other words, I am unsure what the domain and codomain are of such a map.

More context: We have the definitions

1. A mapping $f$ of an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is called smooth if it has continuous partial derivatives of all orders.
2. A map $f:X \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ defined on an arbitrary subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called smooth if it may be locally extended to a smooth map on open sets.

And the problem in question: 
If $k$<$l$ we can consider $\mathbb{R}^k$ to be the subset {$(a_{1},...,a_{k},0,...,0)$} in $\mathbb{R}^l$. Show that smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^k$, considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^l$, are the same as usual.

Comment: Can you give a complete context? This is unclear.

Comment: The definitions are well-known; the additional context that would be useful is the statements in which "smooth on $\mathbb{R}^k$" is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map which is "smooth on $\mathbb{R}^k$" is a smooth map with domain $\mathbb{R}^k$.  More generally, a map "on" a set is a map whose domain is that set.  The codomain is not specified if you say "smooth on $\mathbb{R}^k$" and nothing else.  If you refer to a "smooth *function* on $\mathbb{R}^k$", that would typically mean a smooth map $\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ (more generally, "functions" on a space are usually maps to the "base field" which may be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or something else depending on context).  Otherwise, you'll have to figure out the codomain from context or other words that are used.